# If we export the table into another DB then does its all triggers also gets exported along with it?

Tags: mysql, triggers, export

If we export the table into another DB then does its all triggers also gets exported along with it?

> **Update**
>
> In context of Randy Minder's reply

is it possible to transfer the schema table from one DB to another?

> **UPDATE** 
>   In context of MATT's Reply

But What should I do If i have to script this export? as in this case I have to change the trigger_Schmea every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass [--triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_triggers) to the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) command if you're not getting triggers already (you should.. it's default)

Comment: When I Click Export o table structure in phpmyadmin, I can see the mysqldump, where i found the --Triggers "table_name", but when I copied the whole part and pasted in other DB I cannot find the triggers copied.. What could be the reason

Comment: @OM The Eternity - I haven't used phpMyAdmin in years. To my knowledge it does not use `mysqldump`. In either case I suggest running the `mysqldump` command directly.

Comment: No Issues, I found It, I just have to change the name of trigger_schema inside the mysqldump of phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

I think not.
You could try to export on table into .sql file and see what scripts are written into it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally an "export" only deals with data. So the answer would be no. But if you script out your source database schema, and execute the script against the target database, all the triggers should come with it, assuming they were scripted as part of the schema.